# Iterate multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a newbie to php, i have the following multidimensional array in joomla.

I have the following array for example using print_r (because it is dynamic):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [pressrelease_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => جريدة الفجر
            [1] => جريدة الفجر
            [2] => جريدة الوطن
            [3] => جريدة أخبار اليوم
            [4] => جريدة الشروق
            [5] => صدى البلد
        )

    [pressrelease_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => url1
            [1] => url2
            [2] => url3
            [3] => url4
            [4] => url5
            [5] => url6
        )

    [pressrelease_desc] => Array
        (
            [0] => بالصور.. وزير المالية يطلق الإصدار السنوي الثاني لـ "موازنة المواطن"
            [1] => دميان: "موازنة المواطن" تفتح المجال لإشراك المواطنين في صياغة السياسات الاقتصادية
            [2] => وزير المالية يطلق الإصدار السنوي الثاني لـ"موازنة المواطن"
            [3] => بمشاركة ممثلين عن البنك الدولي و6 وزارات وخبراء المجتمع المدني.. الثلاثاء .. وزير المالية يطلق الإصدار السنوي الثاني لموازنة المواطن
            [4] => وزير المالية: إصدار صكوك إسلامية لتلبية احتياجات شريحة جديدة من المدخرين
            [5] => اليوم.. "المالية" تطلق إصدارها الثاني لموازنة المواطن
        )

)
```

Below is a code to iterate on the press releases array. The problem it only shows 3 results not less not more.

```
<?php
    //$press_releases= json_decode($params->get('repeated_press'),true);
    $press_release = json_decode($attribs->repeated_press);

    $press_n = count((array)$press_release);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $press_n ; $x++) {
        echo '<div class="press_item" id="press_item'.($x+1).'">';
        echo '<div class="title">'.$press_release->pressrelease_title[$x].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="url"><a target="_blank" href="'.$press_release->pressrelease_url[$x].'">'.$press_release->pressrelease_desc[$x].'</a></div>';
        echo '</div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you want to iterate over values of parent array you need to use foreach inside foreach

Comment: Think about what you count here: `$press_n = count((array)$press_release);`

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: It loops 3 indexes, the `stdClass` object. You should have an **inner loop** or loop `$array['pressrelease_title']` by index so it counts also for the other content. Also, this question has been asked soo many times.. A search didn't do you no help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your count to be the number of elements in each array, not the number of arrays.

Change

```
$press_n = count((array)$press_release);
```

To

```
$press_n = count($press_release->pressrelease_title);
```

The 2nd line will count elements in the first member of `$press_release` (the first of your 3 array blocks)